# Google AppEngine application log assigned to the wrong request log

Tags: google-app-engine, kotlin, logging

When I look at the logs in the Google Log Viewer for my GAE project, I see that often the logs that I write myself in the code are assigned to the wrong request. Most of the time the log is assigned to the request directly after the request that produced the log entry.
As the root of every application log in GAE must be a request, this means that the wrong request is sometimes marked as error, because another request before produced an error, but the log is somehow assigned to the request after that.

I don't really do anything special, I use Ktor as my servlet and have an interceptor that creates a log when an exception occurs before returning status 500.
I use Java logging via SLF4J with the google cloud logging handler, but before that I used logback via SLf4J and had the same problem.

The content of the logs itself is also correct, the returned status of the request, the level of the log entry,  the message, everything is ok.

I thought that it may be because I use kotlin and switch coroutine contexts during a single request, but in some cases the point where I write the log and where I send the response are exactly next to each other, so I'm not sure if kotlin has anything to do with it.

My logging.properties:

```
# To use this configuration, add to system properties : -Djava.util.logging.config.file="/path/to/file"
#
.level = INFO

# it is recommended that io.grpc and sun.net logging level is kept at INFO level,
# as both these packages are used by Stackdriver internals and can result in verbose / initialization problems.
io.grpc.netty.level=INFO
sun.net.level=INFO

handlers=com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingHandler
# default : java.log
com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingHandler.log=custom_log

# default : INFO
com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingHandler.level=INFO

# default : ERROR
com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingHandler.flushLevel=WARNING

# default : auto-detected, fallback "global"
#com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingHandler.resourceType=container

# custom formatter
com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format=%1$tY-%1$tm-%1$td %1$tH:%1$tM:%1$tS %4$-6s %2$s %5$s%6$s%n

#optional enhancers (to add additional fields, labels)
#com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingHandler.enhancers=com.example.logging.jul.enhancers.ExampleEnhancer
```

My logging relevant dependencies:

```
  implementation "org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:1.7.30"
  implementation "com.google.cloud:google-cloud-logging:1.100.0"
```

An example logging call:

```
exception<Throwable> { e ->
      logger().error("Error", e)
      call.respondText(e.message ?: "", ContentType.Text.Plain, HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
    }
```

with `logger()` being:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

inline fun <reified T : Any> T.logger(): Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(T::class.java)
```

Edit:
An example of the log in Google cloud. The first request has the query parameter `GAID=cdda802e-fb9c-47ad-0794d394c913`, but as you can see the error log for that request is in the one below, marked in red.

[image: log viewer example]

Comment: Could you please share the screenshot of the requests logs behavior?

Comment: @NibrassH added the log, sorry for the redactions but I don't know what my employer is ok with, so I removed any domains and packages

Comment: Is this occurred for logs that happen in quick succession, like if one request produced an error and then there was some wait instead of immediately another error log, would it still happen. Is there any noticeable difference in the circumstances of when it happens and when it doesn't?

Comment: I don't think I have any request where it doesn't happen. It can take seconds or milliseconds between requests, the log entry is always one request later. Which also means that I don't see any log entry for the last request until there is another one.

Comment: I understand your issue. Are you using App Engine Standard or Flexible?

Comment: We use the Standard Environment

Comment: The best option here is to create a [support ticket](https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/support) in Google Cloud Platform Support in order to investigate further analyzing your app and logs in App Engine.

Comment: Sorry, but your link takes me to the Google Maps support. As far as I see I have to be at least silver support member to be able to open a ticket, so that's sadly probably not an option for me

Comment: Sorry for the wrong link, here is the correct link [1](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/manage-cases#creating_cases).Unfortunately I can't look further as I need to see in detail the app engine app and logs behavior to determine the issue.